# Spring Boot Actuator - Java Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a sample actuator health  check in our infrastructure model which we are consuming in our main service (adding dependencies to the package, @Import class name, etc.).

We know about the http endpoint, by adding the suffix  `/actuator/health`, below is the result:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "components": {
        "com......DbServiceValidator": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "com......StorageServiceValidator": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 505370734592,
                "free": 362675372032,
                "threshold": 10485760,
                "exists": true
            }
        },
        "ping": {
            "status": "UP"
        }
    }
}
```

But we want to get all this data programmatically, from java code.
I did some research but found nothing.

Is it possible to get the data (/json) directly from the code (without rest, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All-in-all there are following strategies you can follow:

1. Use JMX. Spring Boot actuator can also expose endpoints via JMX in addition to REST.
   See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints). So you could write a code that programmatically accesses the "health" mbean and gets the aggregated information.
2. Try to inject the `HealthEndpoint` (it should be a bean, although I've never tried that by myself) into your class and obtain the information about the health by directly calling the object from your server (as if its a regular class) - you'll get the object that logically represents the information from the JSon. The source code of the health endpoint is available [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthEndpoint.java)

Answer (score 3):

There are some auto-configured beans by Spring Boot called `HealthIndicators`, full list [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-indicators).

Should be possible to use it like this:

```
@Autowired
DiskSpaceHealthIndicator diskSpaceHealthIndicator;

void getDiskStatus() {
    logger.info("Current Disk status {}", diskSpaceHealthIndicator.health().getStatus());
}
```

### Edit:

Inspired by the answer from @MarkBramnik I verified that is possible to inject the `HealthEndpoint` and print the result as JSON:

```
@Autowired
private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

public void printHealthStatus() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    log.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(healthEndpoint.health().getStatus()));
    // output is: {"status":"UP"}
}
```